# get directories using ARGV for perl

Tags: perl, argv

```
   $args = @ARGV;

foreach $ARGV (@ARGV)
{
$guitestsDir = "v:\\stuf\\comment\\logs\\$ARGV\\";

############################open logs folder#########################   
if ( -d $guitestsDir ) {
    opendir( DIR, $guitestsDir );
    while ( defined( $pathofdir = readdir(DIR) ) ) {
        next if ( $pathofdir eq "." );
        next if ( $pathofdir eq ".." );
        next unless (-d "$guitestsDir/$pathofdir");
        push (@pathallSuites, $pathofdir);
    }
    closedir(DIR);
}


print "@pathallSuites\n";
```

hi, I will give directory 1 and 2 as argument. in dir 1 will be **dir a and b** in dir 2 **c and d** 
 when I run it for  `print "@pathallSuites\n";` the output will be:

```
a b
a b c d
```

and should be

```
a b
c d
```

what am I doing wrong?
thanks

Comment: `$ARGV` is a predefined variable, which contains the name of the current filehandle while reading from `<>`. http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$ARGV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never reset the `@pathAllSuites` variable. At the beginning of your foreach loop, you need to do this yourself.

```
foreach $ARGV (@ARGV)
{
$#pathAllSuites = -1; # Set the 'last index' to -1, effectively clearing it.
$guitestsDir = "v:\\stuf\\comment\\logs\\$ARGV\\";
```

Comment: `$#pathAllSuites = -1` is an unnecessarily arcane way of writing `@pathAllSuites = ()`

Comment: And better would be just declaring it in the for loop: `foreach $ARGV (@ARGV) {  my @pathallSuites; ...`

Answer (score 2):

The immediate problem is that you aren't emptying `@pathallSuites` between executions of the `foreach` loop, but behind that is the issue that you don't have `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` in place, which *must always* appear at the top of every Perl program you write. Then Perl will reset the array for you if you declare it within the loop

I suggest that you make use of [`glob`](https://p3rl.org/glob) to search for files and directories, and use the [`File::Spec::Functions`](https://p3rl.org/File::Spec::Functions) library to manipulate file paths instead of basic string functions which are more prone to mistakes

The result is much more concise code, as shown here. The call to [`grep`](https://p3rl.org/grep) filters the result of `glob` so that it contains only directory names without any file names

Note that this program differs from your own in that the output is the *full path* to each subdirectory instead of just the name of the subdirectory. If you really want just then name then it's trivial to change, but I thought it was more likely that you really needed the whole thing. Do let me know if I'm wrong

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use File::Spec::Functions 'catdir';

use constant ROOT_DIR => 'V:/stuf/comment/logs';

for my $subdir ( @ARGV ) {

    my @path_all_suites = grep -d, glob catdir(ROOT_DIR, $subdir, '*');

    print "$_\n" for @path_all_suites;
    print "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a condensed version, with all going into a single line of output:

```
print map( "$_ ", map( glob( "$_/*/" ), @ARGV )), "\n";
```

Or a single column:

```
print map( "$_\n", map( glob( "$_/*/" ), @ARGV ));
```